# Starting & Ending Loops with Eager Loaded Elements

Tags: forloop, loop, eager-loading

Basically, I have two sections of a page. In one section of the page, I want to output the first 8 entries in a loop. In the next section of a page, I want to output from the 9th entry to the end of the loop. The entries that I'm looping through are eager loaded.

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
{% set clients = element.clients.find({
    with: [
        ['logo', {
            withTransforms: ['newClientLogoPage']
        },]
    ]})
%}

SECTION #1:
{% for client in clients %}   
    {% if loop.index0 <= 7 %}
        DO SOME STUFF

SECTION #2:
{% for client in clients %} 
    {% if loop.index0 >= 8 %} 
        DO SOME STUFF
```

Essentially, I'm fully looping through the same entries twice and just starting and ending what is output at different spots using loop index.

Is there a better / more efficient way to start and end my loops at different points without doing two full loops like I am now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this nugget about [Iterating over a Subset](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-a-subset) in the Twig docs about slice:

```
{% for client in clients|slice(0, 8) %}
    ... 
{% endfor %}

{% for client in clients|slice(8) %}
      ...
{% endfor %}
```

More details about [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html).